# Appium/TestNG Test shows TimeoutException even if the element is already visible

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, appium

I tried the test with the "noReset" capability set to "true" (user is already logged in) and with only these statements in the Test method at first:

```
assertTrue(app.dashboardPage().isDashboardOpened());

Thread.sleep(5000);

app.dashboardPage().clickProfileIcon();        
assertTrue(app.profilePage().isProfileOpened());

app.profilePage().openSettings();
assertTrue(app.settingsPage().isSettingsOpened());

app.settingsPage().clickNotificationSettings();
assertTrue(app.notificationPage().isNotificationOpened());

assertTrue(app.notificationPage().isToggleOff());
```

and it passes.

However, my test fails when I try to add these statements in the test (user has to login first)

```
doLogin();

if (app.onboardingPage().isNotificationMessageDisplayed() == true) {
    app.onboardingPage().clickNo();
} 

if (app.onboardingPage().isUpdateRealAgeDisplayed() == true) {          
    app.onboardingPage().clickNo();
} 

if (app.onboardingPage().isLaterVisible() == true) {
    app.onboardingPage().clickLater();
    assertTrue(app.onboardingPage().isContinueLaterVisible());
    app.onboardingPage().clickDialogYes();
}
```

I don't get how it could have a TimeOutException when I can see *profile_icon* on the screen. I already tried changing the wait duration but it will still produce the TimeOutException.

Here are my classes:

---

**Test Class**

```
@BeforeMethod
public void connect() throws MalformedURLException {        
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Sony Xperia XA Ultra");
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "---");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", ".ui.MainActivity");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    app = new App(driver);
}

public void doLogin() {
    app.landingPage().allowPermission();
    app.landingPage().goToLoginPage();

    credentials = new UserCredentials("lmpgdn@gmail.com", "11111111");

    app.loginPage().enterEmailAddress(credentials.getEmailAddress());
    app.loginPage().enterPassword(credentials.getPassWord());
    app.loginPage().clickLogin();  

    assertTrue(app.onboardingPage().isOnboardingOpened());
}

@Test (priority = 2)
public void dontAllowNotifications() throws InterruptedException {
    doLogin();

    if (app.onboardingPage().isNotificationMessageDisplayed() == true) {
        app.onboardingPage().clickNo();
    } 

    if (app.onboardingPage().isUpdateRealAgeDisplayed() == true) {          
        app.onboardingPage().clickNo();
    } 

    if (app.onboardingPage().isLaterVisible() == true) {
        app.onboardingPage().clickLater();
        assertTrue(app.onboardingPage().isContinueLaterVisible());
        app.onboardingPage().clickDialogYes();
    }

    assertTrue(app.dashboardPage().isDashboardOpened());

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    app.dashboardPage().clickProfileIcon();        
    assertTrue(app.profilePage().isProfileOpened());

    app.profilePage().openSettings();
    assertTrue(app.settingsPage().isSettingsOpened());

    app.settingsPage().clickNotificationSettings();
    assertTrue(app.notificationPage().isNotificationOpened());

    assertTrue(app.notificationPage().isToggleOff());
}
```

**PageObject Class**

```
public void clickProfileIcon() {
    waitForElementToBeClickable(profile_icon, 15);
    profile_icon.click();
}

public boolean isDashboardOpened() {
    try {
        waitForElementToBeVisibleBy(By.id("toolbar"), 15);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) { return false; }
}

@AndroidFindBy(id="toolbar")
private MobileElement toolbar;

@AndroidFindBy(xpath="/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/"
        + "android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/"
        + "android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/"
        + "android.widget.ViewAnimator/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/"
        + "android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/"
        + "android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageButton")
private MobileElement profile_icon;
```

**Result**

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: Located by Locator map: 
>   - native content: "By.chained({By.xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[3]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.ViewAnimator/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCGcO.png)/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ImageButton})" 
>   - html content: "by id or name "profile_icon"" (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCGcO.png)

Comment: Could you post the UIautomator screenshot of the element. Currently I think that the xpath is incorrect. I try to avoid using that long xpaths  like this.

Comment: I just copied the xpath that the automator showed. Will it make a difference if I just use "//android.widget.ImageButton"? And I attached a screenshot in the post now.

Comment: I would prefer to use the following xpath. 
 //android.view.viewGroup[@resource-id='com.sharecare.droz:id/toolbar']/android.widget.imageButton  . Trying to find using //android.widget.ImageButton will choose the first image button it finds which could be actually some other image button.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion! I will implement that for my xpath values.